# Double machine learning (DML): intercept in final linear model?

Tags: causality

I'm using double machine learning (DML) to estimate a conditional average treatment effect (CATE). The main idea is as follows, see [here](https://econml.azurewebsites.net/spec/estimation/dml.html#overview-of-formal-methodology) for more info.

\begin{split}
Y - E[Y | X, W] = \theta(X) * (T - E[T | X, W])
\end{split}

The first two models, to estimate the outcome (Y) and the treatment (T), are gradient boosting machines. For the final model, which regresses the residuals on each other, is a linear model.

In this final linear model, can I use an intercept? Normally it should not be necessary since the residuals that I'm regressing on each other should have zero mean. However, I'm fitting the final linear model on a different dataset than the first two models to avoid having biased residuals because of overfitting. In this case it means that the distribution of my residuals have non-zero mean.

Hence my question: can I use an intercept in this case or should I still proceed without?